# Проверка на пустую ячейку в sql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, функции

```
BEGIN
    declare countRow INT default 0;
    DECLARE idRow INT DEFAULT 0;

    SELECT count(*), id
    INTO countRow, idRow
    FROM `film`
    WHERE `name` LIKE nameFilm
      AND `original_name` LIKE original_name1
      AND `year` LIKE year1
    GROUP BY id;

    IF countRow > 0 THEN
        UPDATE `film` SET name = nameFilm,original_name = original_name1,description = description1, world_rating = world_rating1,russia_rating = russia_rating1, time = time1, cash = cash1,budget = budget1,year = year1,dateRF = dateRF1, dateW = dateW1, poster = poster1, trailer = trailer1
        WHERE id = idRow; 
    ELSE
        INSERT film (name,original_name,description,world_rating,russia_rating,time,cash,budget,year,dateRF,dateW,poster,trailer)
        VALUES (nameFilm,original_name1,description1,world_rating1,russia_rating1,time1,cash1,budget1,year1,dateRF1,dateW1,poster1,trailer1);

        SELECT id
        INTO idRow
        FROM film
        WHERE name LIKE nameFilm
          AND original_name LIKE original_name1
          AND year LIKE `year1`;
    END IF;

    RETURN idRow;
END
```

Функция проверяет про 3м параметрам на дубликаты и в соответствии вставляет или обновляет записи. Суть в том, что если один из параметров приходит пустым, то она возвращает 0, вместо id.
Как можно не сильно громоздко сделать проверку на то, что параметр приходит пустым и если приходит, то сравнивать уже по 2м параметрам.

Comment: в принципе решил проблему проверкой на пустоту в php и добавлением еще одной функции, сравнивающей по 2м параметрам, но рационально ли это..

Comment: Пустым может быть только один параметр?

Comment: `column = coalesce(param, column)`

Comment: А like используется потому как в параметрах приходят в нужных местах `%` и нужен поиск по примерному совпадению или потому что знак `=` чем то не нравиться ? И что должно происходить при пустом параметре - искаться записи с любым значением поля или именно с пустым ?

Comment: И кстати id последней вставленной записи возвращает функция `LAST_INSERT_ID()` делать повторный запрос в таблицу по всем параметрам поиска не рационально

Comment: Хотя стоп ... вы же потом вставляете пришедшие параметры поиска в БД. значит использовать like нельзя ни в коем случае иначе, например название `100% серого` будет считаться совпадающим скажем с `100 оттенков серого`

Comment: возможно для этого я по нескольким параметрам сравниваю

Comment: И все таки, почему именно `like` а не обычное `=`, ведь он медленнее, нечеткий (что очень странно с учетом последующего update). И уж год, который 4 цифры как то like сравнивать ну ооочень странно.

Comment: Просто если вы хотите именно нечеткий поиск то выглядеть будет так, я ищу "какой нибудь фильм содержащий слово 'любовь'" задаю в имени фильма `%любовь%`, он находит первый попавшийся фильм, например 'любовь и голуби' и тут же меняет update его название на переданное '%любовь%' ... Отсюда я заключил, что вы не понимаете особенностей работы оператора `like`, а хотели использовать простое сравнение на точное равенство, что делается оператором `=` вместо `like`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WHERE (`name` LIKE nameFilm or nameFilm is null)
      AND (`original_name` LIKE original_name1 or original_name1 is null)
      AND (`year` LIKE year1 or year1 is null)
```

Любой их параметров может быть null.

Comment: оо
так можно оказывается
пасиб
надо пробовать